# PostgreSQL: How to convert character to have decimal?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field with `char(6)` datatype and the value is form of a integer. (eg. 33568,34048,37744)

All I want is to convert it to have decimal like this:

```
2000 = 200.00 

33568 = 335.68 

34048 = 340.48 

37744 = 377.44
```

I tried using

`cast( "Field"  as decimal(10,2))`

`Cast(Replace("Field",' ','.') as decimal(18,2))`

But I can't get what I expected.

PostgreSQL please.

Answer (score 1):

you can create this feature to facilitate and refactor your Requet :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION character_decimal(texttoconvert character varying,i integer) RETURNS double precision AS $$
    BEGIN
            RETURN (case when length(texttoconvert) > i then left(texttoconvert, -i) else '0' end 
                    || '.' 
                    || case when length(texttoconvert) > 0 then right(texttoconvert, i) else '0' end ) :: double precision;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select character_decimal('2000',2);-->20.00
select character_decimal('33568',2);-->335.65
select character_decimal('34048',2);-->340.48
select character_decimal('37744',2);-->377.44
```

Comment: If this query respond to your question.Please consider this questions as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the period to the string?

```
select left(col, -2) || '.' || right(col, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! :D